# DataReader, DataColumn - Can These Show Me Columns In Schema Such as SomeSchema.SomeColumn?

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, schema, datacolumn

I have a database table where columns are in multiple schemas.  Example:

```
SomeTable
SomeSchema.Column1
SomeSchema.Column2
AnotherSchema.ColumnA
AnotherSchema.ColumnB
```

I have code using a `DataTable.Rows[r][c].ToString()` syntax and it looks like only the `Column1` or `ColumnA` part is being returned.  I need to get the full name `SomeSchema.Column1` as right now it seems the code is throwing a Sql Exception with Column1 not found.  I'm assuming that if I can reference it as `SomeSchema.Column1` that this will correct the exception.  Can I get this using a `DataTable` or `DataColumn` or is there another approach I need to take for this?  Any ideas?  I have searched Google and this site with such keywords as "C# datatable datacolumn schema table dbo" and have not had much luck.

Comment: You have Columns in schemata? Which DBMS?

Comment: I'm confused. If you're getting a SQL Exception, that's a problem with your query, not with the DataTable. Also, DataTables do have metadata; you can index into a DataRow by column name. If the column name doesn't exist, then your code isn't matching the column names returned by the query. Without seeing real code and the full exception, it's hard to say what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

LMAO, I've been working on this too long without a break I think... it's not the columns that have the schema, it is the table, so I think I can tweak my query to get the table name with the schema which I think will feed right in to my existing code and all will be good... I'll post back after it's done and tested... sigh...

Comment: Yeah, sorry... I changed my query to get all tables in database from select name from sys.tables to select schema_name(schema_id) + '.' + name from sys.tables and I'm now getting the full table name which should avoid the exception.  Going to bed now... thanks and sorry for the confusion...
Jason